# SDL2 iOS app: Entry point (_main) undefined for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, sdl, sdl-2

I built a small game using SDL2, SDL2_ttf, and SDL2_mixer. I ported it to Xcode and was able to run it with the iOS simulator just fine. I successfully built all of the SDL2 libraries with the target set to "iOS Device" and imported them into the Frameworks directory of my project. However, when I tried to archive the project with the target set to "iOS Device" I get the following error:

```
ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture armv7 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this issue casued b7 the SDL libraries I'm trying to link to or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I bet the SDL lib doesn't contain a valid armv7 slice but your app is being built for arm7 and arm64.

Check the SDL build settings and make sure that the 'valid architectures` include armv7

Comment: In the SDL build settings, Valid Archiectures contains "arm64 armv7 armv7s", so it doesn't look that was the issue.

Comment: And active architectures?

Comment: Under "Architectures" it lists "Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)"

Comment: Ok. And who provides the Main function?